# I am the biggest bow, but not even the strongest man can lift me

Tags: riddle

I am the biggest bow, but not even the strongest man can lift me. Looking at me can make your heart quiver, but I have no arrows. What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guess it's

> a rainbow

since

> unliftable, inspiring, arrow-less.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not the desired answer, but:

> I live near the Bow river, which is 587 km in length. There's some debate about the "size" of a rainbow, since it's a visual phenomenon and it's size depends on point of observation. Anyhoo, the Bow river is quite scenic (hearts aquiver) and has no arrows.

Answer (score 3):

What about "Orion's Bow", part of the constellation Orion?  It's far, far bigger than any of the other answers and meets all the other criteria.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to share another answer I heard:

> I am the Titanic

because

> The bow of the Titanic was really big, the strongest man cannot lift the Titanic, the bow of the ship cannot be used to shoot an arrow, and the ending of Titanic was somewhat of a tear-jerker.

Answer (score 1):

Are you an:

> el-bow.

Not even the strongest man can lift me.

> Not even a strong man can lift his own elbow.

Looking at me can make your heart quiver

> You can get tennis elbow - nudge, nudge, wink, wink.

But I have no arrows

> Elbows are used to fire arrows, and are not arrows themselves.

Comment: why the downvote? +1 for compensation

Comment: I can lift my elbow. I don't think I'm the only one.